# Android Play Store asking users for a permission that is no longer present in the current production APK

Tags: android, permissions, google-play

The previous version of the APK had the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission enabled in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Now, the currently published APK does not need writing to external storage anymore, so I removed that line from the manifest.

In the APK information tab in the Google Play Developer console the newest APK shows no permissions needed (it does for previous versions).

Do I have to perform any additional changes/options so Google Play does not request that permission anymore?

EDIT

As additional information:

- The APK has no upgrade packages in it BUT
- Just after installing it you can see that there is an UPDATE in the Play Store and you can try and update it without additional permissions needed BUT
- When you try to update it it shows one warning/error icon with the notification: "Application already exists" and it won't let you update it.

So I guess that what is happening is that users are still installing the previous APK and then they should upgrade it but this can't be done.

What can be happening?

**LAST EDIT**

Not knowing specifically how the process of version replacement takes place in Google Plays store this issue seems related to it.

While the version replacement is still happening it looks like you don't directly install the last version even if it is available in the store. You install the previous version with its permissions and then you "update" to the new one in "background mode". This forces you to accept the previous version permissions for some time.

When the last version totally replaces the previous one in the store then only the new permission acknowledgement dialog is triggered.

Comment: That should be all that's needed going forward at this point for your latest released application.

Comment: I'm afraid this may be only a Play Store publishing lag issue. The version in the Play Store is not the last one but the last update is already available for 2 days.

Comment: I have same issue, any progress with this? Thanks. @SaintJob2.0

Comment: @Michael Drdlíček Maybe the last edit to this post may help you or any other one that visits this post.